# Find most heavily edited file in git commit

Tags: git, github

Say I make a commit to a git repository with a lot of files changed.

How can I find out which file got changed the most in this specific commit?
(the most lines of code changed/removed/added)

Is it then also possible to find out what is the filesize change of this file?

Comment: What do you mean by "changed the most" ?

Comment: For which icons the most lines of code got changed/removed/added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One close approximation could be to use `--numstat` to output the amount of lines changes in each file and sort accordingly. This will produce a list of files sorted from the file with the most lines added to it in this commit to the one with the least:

```
$ git show <commit hash> --pretty=tformat: --numstat | sort -nr
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it then also possible to find out what is the filesize change of this file?

To get the file size use this:

```
git ls-tree -r -l <commit> <file path>
```